# Codeigniter HMVC modules and javascript files

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, hmvc

I've just started learning about HMVC in CodeIgniter.

So far I've been enjoying having modular controllers, but problems come when I wish to include javascript.

It seems to me that I'll have to include javascript file from the view instead of the widgets which isn't really good because I tend to forget which widgets has to come with which javascript file.

Anyone has a better way to do it?

Comment: could you post some code to explain? I don't understand what you mean by widgets (controllers?) and it would be best to see how you include your JS files in your views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets (css,js,images) you should place outside of application folder so you can access them directly.

Thus , you load them using base_url() to start with, and base_url() remains same from wherever you call it.

if you want to split assets in modules as well, perhaps make an assets folder, which further contains folders with module names, each containing css,js,images files. then use `base_url()."/assets/module_name/js/script.js"`
or something of the sort

Comment: How can I call my JS file placed in the module as module_name/controller|model|view|js

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to place the javascript file in the "Application" folder. Because of the .htaccess file and the way codeigniter framework redirects work, direct access to the files in the application folder is not possible, so you can't/shouldn't place it there.

Answer (score 1):

As default, you cannot access files within your module folder as it was protected by .htaccess in applications folder.

To allow access in your assets/public folder within your module folder just add another .htaccess within the folder and add the following line.

`Allow From All`